# Medir tempo de uma rotina em Ruby

Tags: funções, ruby, runtime

Existe alguma função em Ruby para medir o tempo de uma função?

Em python eu uso:

```
ini = time.time()
#função
fim = time.time()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Opção 1:** Você pode fazer algo bem parecido com o *Python*, usando a classe [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html).

Exemplo:

```
ini = Time.now
#funcao
fim = Time.now

#tempo_resultante vai ser do tipo float    
tempo_resultante = fim - ini
```

**Opção 2:** Usando o módulo [Benckmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

Exemplo:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(7) do |x| #o 7 é o tamanho da coluna na saida
  x.report("funcao x:"){ 
       #funcao que deseja testar
  }
end
```

Saída:

```
                user     system      total        real
 funcao x:     1.050000   0.000000   1.050000 (  0.503462)
```

Observações:

```
user:  tempo de CPU do usuário
system:  tempo de CPU do sistema
total:  soma dos tempos de CPU do sistema e usuário
real: tempo real total decorrido

obs: todos os tempos são dados em segundos
```